# licensing open source software

Tags: licensing

As a newbie, I am quite confused how open source software is can/be licensed. I know of licenses like GNU public, Apache, and others.

What is the procedure to license a open source software by developer? What considerations should be made? What choices do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the developer you are free to license your software (provided you aren't developing the software for someone else) in whatever way you wish. You have all the choice in the world and you should choose a license that meets your needs. Beyond that, any advice is rhetoric.

Answer (score 2):

Technically most open source software aren't 'licenced'. You don't buy a licence to use it. You just use it. The "GNU General Public Licence" is not really a software licence that you accept or decline, it's a copyright licence

Books are copyrighted, you can't go photocopying a whole book, and sell it yourself. However you don't 'buy' book licences. Open Source software is like that.

Comment: A license doesn't have to be purchased and you accept OSS licenses through your use of the software accompanied by the specified License. OSS licenses very much *are* real software licenses and carry the full weight of the law.

Comment: No, you don't accept an OSS licence by using it. You are only allowed to copy/share/build on the OSS software in accordance with the licence. *Nothing* in an OSS licence covers usage. OSS licences carry the full weight of *copyright* law, not contract law.

Answer (score 2):

There's no big scary procedure. :) All you have to do is drop a file named LICENSE with your license of choice inside of it into your project's root directory and make it obvious that that file is the license for the entire project, either through comments in the source code or a notice in the README.

Choose any license you want. A quick google search can get you on your way.

One of the most commonly used ones in open source is the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).